# How to load DLL and create a new instance in C#?

Tags: c#, dll

I want to load a DLL file if it exists, and create a new instance of it, cast it and pass to another function.

What I currently do is to add a reference to the DLL, and create an instance, e.g.,

```
ConfigFileSystemRegistry.Instance.RegisterFileSystem("er://", new Efs());
```

I tried to load it dynamically, but it's giving a `System.TypeInitializationException`

My code used is:

```
        if (File.Exists("plugin\\Efsystem.dll"))
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("plugin\\Efsystem.dll");
            Type type = assembly.GetType("Efs");
            ConfigFileSystemRegistry.Instance.RegisterFileSystem("er://", (IFileSystem) Activator.CreateInstance(type));
        }
```

Comment: What is an instance of a DLL?

Comment: sorry I meant instance of a specific class in the DLL.

Comment: What's the exception message of the `System.TypeInitializationException`?

Comment: Failed to load module from assembly

Comment: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type

------------------------------
System.ArgumentNullException

------------------------------
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and add relevant information to it, not to comments.

Comment: TypeInitializationException happens when clr fails to initialize a type. You can find more detail by checking the inner exception of this exception. I am guessing that the static constructor of your Efs type is causing that exception.

Answer (score 1):

`System.TypeInitializationException` implies your static constructor is throwing an exception. Check the inner exception and the stack trace for hints.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the existence of a default constructor. If there isn't, see what arguments you need, and call the override of CreateInstance with the `params object[] args` argument.